# SQLCMD batch job using impersonation

Tags: batch-file, impersonation, sqlcmd

I have a batch file executing SQLCMD for each sql file in the directory:

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -U user -P password -E -i"%%G"
```

But I have to make use of impersonation and I don't want to have the line for this in each file. I have tried 2 possible solutions.

Solution 1:

```
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -U user -P password -E -q "EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'user2'" -i"%%G" -q "REVERT"
```

Solution 2:

```
sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -U user -P password -E -q "EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'user2'"
for %%G in (*.sql) do sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -U user -P password -E -i"%%G" 
sqlcmd /S servername /d databaseName -U user -P password -E -q "REVERT"
```

But both solutions aren't working. What to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx):

> **-i** *input_file* [, *input_file2* ...]
>
> Identifies the file that contains a batch of SQL statements or stored procedures. [...] **The -i and the -Q/-q options are mutually exclusive**.

So you can't use `sqlcmd` in this way. But you could use the `osql` utility instead, which doesn't seem to have this limitation, although, if you just replace all `sqlcmd` entries with `osql` in either of your solutions, it still won't work.

Your second method wouldn't work because of the scope of [`EXECUTE AS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx), which is the current session or the current module, or until [`REVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178632.aspx) is executed. Since every invocation of `osql` would initiate a new session, calling `EXECUTE AS` separately from your scripts wouldn't have any effect on them.

The first solution wouldn't work because `osql` would execute both `-q` commands before the `-i` script. So, you would effectively be both changing the execution context *and* reverting it back *before* the script.

However, you don't need to explicitly call `REVERT` at the end of execution of every script. So, just take your first solution, replace `sqlcmd` with `osql`, remove the `-q "REVERT"` bit and go with what remains.

Comment: Hi Andriy, I've tried that also, but I get a message that -q and -i are mutually exclusive...

Comment: I didn't get that impression when I was testing this on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. However, I had to use `osql` instead of `sqlcmd`, because the users I was testing on were passwordless and `sqlcmd` doesn't work well with passwordless users. Maybe you could try with `osql`?

Comment: I've tried it another time. Now not getting the mutually exclusive message, but getting a dos prompt with the text: 1>

Comment: When I enter exit it looks like the SP are deployed, but I then get a message that I haven't the correct rights, meaning that the impersonation isn't executed correctly before.

Comment: I get the mutually exclusive message with version 2007.100.1600.22, I get the DOS prompt containing 1> with version 2007.100.5500.0.

Comment: You are right about mutual exclusivity of `-q` and `-i`. Please see my update.

Comment: Great! That's doing the job! Thank you very much!